# Book in which a rogue AI infects a ship captain with a virus which turns her into an insect-like creature

Tags: story-identification, novel, spaceship, artificial-intelligence

Looking for a novel in which a malevolent, rogue AI infects a ship captain with a virus which turns her into an insect-like creature.

This rogue AI is being hunted - possibly it has a price on its head. In this novel the various planets are controlled by gatekeeper, very powerful AIs. I read this novel around 2015-2019 perhaps.

Answer (score 14):

Sounds like Neal Asher's [*Dark Intelligence*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22859850-dark-intelligence) (2015), part of his Polity series, where artificial intelligences run an interplanetary civilization and often have enormous and powerful ship-bodies. Most of the series is set after a war with the crablike and carnivorous Prador, whose advanced technologies challenged even the abilities of the AIs and left the Polity with a number of traumatized war machines.

The relevant summary on Goodreads:

> Isobel Satomi ran a successful crime syndicate. But after competitors attacked, she needed more power. Yet she got more than she bargained for when she negotiated with Penny Royal. She paid it to turn her part-AI herself, but the upgrades hid a horrifying secret. The Dark AI had triggered a transformation in Isobel that would turn her into a monster, rapidly evolving into something far from human.

Comment: Sorry for the edit clash. Tried to fix it

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Thanks! Was trying to get an answer in before Valorum for once...

Comment: @HighDesertSnow If you're sure, please click the checkmark under the vote count so we know for posterity that this is indeed the book you were thinking of.